# Reactive Framework / DoubleClick

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I know that there is an easy way to do this - but it has beaten me tonight ...

I want to know if two events occur within 300 milliseconds of each other, as in a double click.

Two leftdown mouse clicks in 300 milliseconds - I know this is what the reactive framework was built for - but damn if I can find a good doc that has simple examples for all the extenstion operatores - Throttle, BufferWithCount, BufferWithTime - all of which just werent' doing it for me....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TimeInterval` method will give you the time between values.

```
public static IObservable<Unit> DoubleClicks<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan doubleClickSpeed, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source
        .TimeInterval(scheduler)
        .Skip(1)
        .Where(interval => interval.Interval <= doubleClickSpeed)
        .RemoveTimeInterval();
}
```

If you want to be sure that triple clicks don't trigger values, you could just use `Repeat` on a hot observable (I've used a `FastSubject` here as the clicks will all come on one thread and therefore don't require the heaviness of the normal Subjects):

```
public static IObservable<TSource> DoubleClicks<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source, TimeSpan doubleClickSpeed, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source.Multicast<TSource, TSource, TSource>(
        () => new FastSubject<TSource>(), // events won't be multithreaded
        values =>
        {
            return values
                .TimeInterval(scheduler)
                .Skip(1)
                .Where(interval => interval.Interval <= doubleClickSpeed)
                .RemoveTimeInterval()
                .Take(1)
                .Repeat();
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I learned a lot from what I thought would have been a very easy exersize.  Where is there complete documentation on all these various extensions??? How did you learn them?

My only question is in regard to the Repeat, as I'm confused as to just when a observer goes out of scope (shy not UnSubscribe)?  If I subscribe in the constructor of my class how is the scope established?  I know that OnComplete calls the dispose, but when is listening to events actually complete?

Comment: @codputer - Most of my knowledge comes from the fact that I wrote unit tests against each operator while I was porting the framework to actionscript. I've since documented most of the operators, although they're a tad out of date now (and I know the Throttle documentation is wrong) - https://github.com/richardszalay/rxas/wiki/Operators

Comment: @codputer - The observer will never go out of scope unless the control in question goes out of scope until the control does (because subscribing to a control's event ties the observer to the control in the object graph). The event subscription won't be removed until you dispose the subscription. Alternatively, you could have it unsubscribe automatically by using `TakeUntil` or some other operator that terminates a subscription.

Comment: @codputer - You would use `Zip` when you want to pair up values from two streams in the order that they arrived. Scott's example was using it to combine a `Timestamp`d stream with _itself_ (skipping the first value of one) in order to select out the _difference_ between the two time values. It simply wasn't necessary for this scenario as there is a built in `TimeInterval` operator.

Answer (score 4):

Edit - Use `TimeInterval()` instead.

The `Zip() and Timestamp()` operators might be a good start.

```
var ioClicks = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventHandler, RoutedEventArgs>(
                                        h => new MouseButtonEventHandler(h),
                                        h => btn.MouseLeftButtonDown += h,
                                        h => btn.MouseLeftButtonDown -= h);
var ioTSClicks = ioClicks.Timestamp();

var iodblClicks = ioTSClicks.Zip(ioTSClicks.Skip(1), 
                                 (r, l) => l.Timestamp - r.Timestamp)
                            .Where(tspan => tspan.TotalMilliseconds < 300);
```

Probably best to test this via the test scheduler, so you know exactly what you're getting:

```
[Fact]
public void DblClick()
{
    // setup
    var ioClicks = _scheduler.CreateHotObservable(
                     OnNext(210, "click"),
                     OnNext(220, "click"),
                     OnNext(300, "click"),
                     OnNext(365, "click"))
                     .Timestamp(_scheduler);

    // act
    Func<IObservable<TimeSpan>> target = 
        () => ioClicks.Zip(ioClicks.Skip(1), 
                          (r, l) => l.Timestamp - r.Timestamp)
                        .Where(tspan => tspan.Ticks < 30);
    var actuals = _scheduler.Run(target);

    // assert
    Assert.Equal(actuals.Count(), 1);
    // + more
}
public static Recorded<Notification<T>> OnNext<T>(long ticks, T value)
{
    return new Recorded<Notification<T>>(
        ticks, 
        new Notification<T>.OnNext(value));
}
```

Comment: Thanks as well - I was close to calling yours the answer, but thought that the FastSubject was interesting to ensure the events all came on the same thread. Did +1 it though!

I'm curious as to where you learned about the Reactive Framework, and your source of documentation for all the various extensions.

Comment: @codputer - I think you misunderstand. My sample uses `FastSubject` _because_ no thread handling is required (ie. mouse clicks always come from the UI thread). It's the normal Subject implementations that protect against values coming in from multiple threads.